# mysql 5.5.50 Calculate one day multiple events to one

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, time

I have a problem with my thinking and I must ask someone to help.
I create simply working time tracking system and I can manage all other things with that code, but I cannot now figure out how I can calculate following data.

Fist, I have couple tables and one store four things.

```
index | who | timestamp           | what
1     | 1   | 2016-09-21 08:00:00 | Work
2     | 2   | 2016-09-21 08:01:00 | Work
3     | 1   | 2016-09-21 10:00:00 | Bin
4     | 2   | 2016-09-21 10:00:00 | Bin
5     | 1   | 2016-09-21 10:15:00 | Bout
6     | 2   | 2016-09-21 10:17:00 | Bout
7     | 2   | 2016-09-21 13:00:00 | Bin
8     | 1   | 2016-09-21 13:00:00 | Bin
9     | 1   | 2016-09-21 13:30:00 | Bout
10    | 2   | 2016-09-21 13:30:00 | Bout
11    | 2   | 2016-09-21 15:58:00 | Home
12    | 1   | 2016-09-21 16:05:00 | Home
```

I can nicely calculate times between Work and Home and got right value to the right person.

But I'm stuck now with those break times.

I need calculate all possible breaks together per person and that way get a total time what is spend to breaks per person.

So I need something like following answer when ask person 1 info:

```
Who | Time     | Breaktime | Working time
1   | 08:05:00 | 00:45:00  | 07:20:00
```

Or maybe all persons can came to same page when ask specific day...

```
Who | Time     | Breaktime | Working time
1   | 08:05:00 | 00:45:00  | 07:20:00
2   | 07:57:00 | 00:47:00  | 07:10:00
```

There is always pairs with events. Work -> Home and Bin -> Bout.
And yes, there is much more persons and could be much more brake times per person.

That might be a bad presentation, sorry about that (NooB). I hope I give that much information as someone can help. But ask if there is something to ask.

That is code what I use when I solve one day total time at working place.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(  
(SELECT timestamp FROM `stamps` WHERE (who like '1' and  DATE (timestamp) like '2016-09-21' and what like 'Home')),
(SELECT timestamp FROM `stamps` WHERE (who like '1' and  DATE (timestamp) like '2016-09-21' and what like 'Work'))
)
```

But I cannot use it with multiple events.

Comment: So what have you done to attempt this yourself? This is not a code writing service, we're not here to do your job for you. You show what you've attempted, we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: Thanks to repair my question Machavity. Now I can do better job next time.

Comment: Marc B. I just thinking if someone could help me out for my brain circle. I try example use same sql than I use with Work -> Home event.
I'm not know yet how I can add it to comment. Do I must make an answer?

Comment: don't post code into comments. it's unreadable. edit your question.

Comment: I think I found some help from other question... I tell answer if I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I found. Maybe not nice, but it works =).

```
$break = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT what, timestamp FROM stamps WHERE (who like '$id' and  DATE (timestamp) like '$day' and what like 'B%') ORDER BY timestamp");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($break))
 {
  if ( $row['what'] == "Bin" )
   $start = strtotime( $row['timestamp'] );
  else { $stop = strtotime( $row['timestamp'] );
   $hours += ( $stop - $start );
   }
 }
$btime = gmdate('H:i:s', floor($hours));
```

$btime gives 00:00:00 style result.

Comment: It always helps when must ask something. When I ask, then I start thinking different =). Many times, its help when someone at least listening.